# How to add this symbol in this position?

Tags: symbols

Could someone help me in how to add the \nabla symbol on top of the \tau symbol?

[image: superior convective derivative]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `accents` package, you have a better spacing and size. I added a shortcut to have indices and exponents in `\scriptscriptstyle`, which looks better, in my opinion, for capital letters. Also, the `diffcoeff` package simplifies typing  derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\usepackage{accents}
\def\sst{\scriptscriptstyle}

\begin{document}

\[ \accentset{\nabla}{\tau}_{\sst P_K} =\diff.D.*{\tau_{\sst P_K}}t -\bigl[\nabla U^{\sst T}\cdot \tau_{\sst P_K}\bigr] - \bigl[\tau_{\sst P_K}\cdot\nabla U\bigr] \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard for pointing out about `diffcoeff.sty`...

Comment: And... if I want to BOLD \tau, how I can do this?

Comment: Use `\boldsymbol{\tau]`, or even define a shortcut: `\def\btau{\boldsymbol{\tau}}`.

Comment: The Latex gives me a error, when I use \boldsymbol{\tau}

Comment: Did you load `amssymb`?

Comment: yes... I use: `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
\stackrel{\nabla}{\tau}
```